# Controller middleware

Tags: laravel

I have controller named `'AdminController'`

And I have a lot of functions in there. The problem is that I dont want in every function user `IF` statement just like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if(Auth::check() && $request->user()->is_admin())
    {
    return view('admin.index');
    }
    else
    {
        flash()->error('You dont have permissions!');
        return redirect('home');
    }
}
```

How can I make it more simple with middleware so I could make everything work without using `IF` statement in every function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware IsAdmin
```

Customize `app/Http/Middleware/IsAdmin.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;
use Closure;

class IsAdmin
{
    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && $request->user()->is_admin())
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

        flash()->error('You dont have permissions!');
        return redirect('home');
    }
}
```

Finally [register and use the middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#registering-middleware)